# Firebase not working iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-notifications

I've checked everything and everything seems to be set up properly but i cant get Firebase push notifications, analytics and crash to work. The database works perfect though.

The app id is set up properly and p12 certificate uploaded. I tested this with OneSignal and notifications work fine though there. Also the App capabilities are set correctly.

I added firebase to my xcode project via cocoapods and have updated to V4.0 (pod update)

The google .plist file was added correctly (or the database wouldn't work)

When I'd initially added firebase to my app the analytics and notifications did work but they were very delayed, stats would only how up hours later but now nothing comes up at all.

Here's AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import OneSignal

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.



        OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: "N/A")



        FirebaseApp.configure()

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()






        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that the data showed up late so it means that it works correctly as intended (see official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/)).

> Getting started with Analytics is easy. Just add the Firebase SDK to your new or existing app, and data collection begins automatically. You can view analytics data in the Firebase console within hours.

Comment: It used to show up late (a couple months ago when I first added the SDK) now it doesn't show at all.

Comment: Only push notification events don't show up or other events (first_open or custom events) don't show up? How long ago did it stop showing any stats? You can turn on DebugView to see real-time debug events to verify that it works or StreamView to see real user data in the past 30 minutes.

Comment: Okay I did that and the analytics are working now, thanks. The push notifications still don't though, any ideas as they work through OneSignal?

Comment: Have you tried looking at FCM issues on their github account at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues ? I think you can find some relevant issues there.